# How to bypass before_filter in application_controller in rails 3.1 integration test with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

There is a before_filter in our rails 3.1 app check the session time out. The problem is that session is not recognized in rspec integration test and caused error in rspec. Is there way we can bypass the before_filter in application_controller? controller.should_receive(:my_filter) does not work here.

Comment: What does the code look like? How do you validate this? You can always add an **unless Rails.env.test?** to the code to avoid running this filter if on the test env.

Comment: The code is to check if session[:last_seen] is xx minutes ago. If it is, reset_session. Bypassing test env works. Is there a way (similar to  controller.should_receive(:my_filter) in controller rspec) for rspec to bypass this filter? This before_filter causes failure in integration tests which passed before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this test in your before filter:

```
before_filter :my_filter

def my_filter
  return if Rails.env.test?
  # check session timeout...
end
```

Comment: Bypassing test env works. Is there a way (similar to controller.should_receive(:my_filter) in controller rspec) for rspec to bypass this filter? This before_filter causes failure in integration tests which passed before.